# Nodejs web application for mqtt using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-applications, mqtt

I want to design a web app capable of publishing message on mqtt broker when a switch state is changed or a form is filled and submitted etc. I am able to publish the message using mqtt library on node. I am also able to detect the normal switch state when it is changed on html page using javascript and jquery. Now I want to call the mqtt publish function from node app here. How will I do it?

Here is the normal html file switch.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="switch.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="switch.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>


<label class="switch" id = "switchLabel1">
  <input type="checkbox" id = "switch1">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

The javascript that detects the switch state switch.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#switch1').attr('checked', true);
    $('#switch1').click(function(){

        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
            console.log("switch1 is checked.");
        }

        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
            console.log("switch1 is unchecked.");
        }

    });
});
```

The Nodejs app publishing message to mqtt index.js. MQTT library is installed using npm.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.15.3')

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('mqtt_node_subscribe')
  client.publish('mqtt_node_publish', 'Hello mqtt')
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer 
  console.log(message.toString())
})
```

What I want to do is call client.publish("topic", "message") when instead of console.log in switch.js

When I do that it says client not defined, so I tried merging both js and running node, it says $ not defined. I tried including jquery in node app, it says window missing. So I need a method to serve this web application using node and use jquery etc as is.

Comment: is there any `mqtt` server running in `192.168.15.3` ?

Comment: Yes, the mqtt server is running on 192.168.15.3

Comment: You have to use a client side mqtt/websocket library to connect to the server first (i mean from web javascript).

Comment: I want this node application to be client in itself which will serve the web page and publish when there is state change in switch

Comment: How will the node server know that there is a switch change? are you sending any request to node server about that?

Comment: Okay, I got the point. You mean my client needs a websocket first to connect to node server or broker. Am I right?

Comment: better have a rest api call to your server and then based on that info connect to mqtt server OR directly connect to live server from web client (probably by generating a secret token from node server).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132180/discussion-between-rishabh-kaushik-and-cerlin-boss).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQTT over a websocket is a difficult approach. The same work can be done using socket.io. It is a js based library giving capabilities of topics publish and subscribe messages. Give it a try.